# Premake OpenGL SDK Cannot Build Project From Tutorial

Tags: c++, opengl, sdk, linker, premake

I'm trying to build the tutorials from http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/index.html and I can't seem to get past the linking part. This is what I get when I go to Tut 01 folder and type in "premake4 gmake" and "make" right after.

```
==== Building framework (debug) ====
==== Building Tut 01 Main (debug) ====
Linking Tut 01 Main
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglloadD
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglimgD
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglutilD
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lglmeshD
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfreeglutD
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [Tut 01 MainD] Error 1
make: *** [Tut 01 Main] Error 2
```

As you can see, it has problems linking the project together. I downloaded  Tutorial 0.3.8.7z from here: https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/gltut/downloads

Comment: Did you build the SDK first, like the instructions say?

Comment: Thanks, it got rid of the error, but now I get this error: http://ix.io/5dP

Comment: @NicolBolas How do I get rid of this error? /usr/bin/ld: note: 'XPending' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line. I looked through the freeglut.lua file and I saw that X11 was already linked... Which is weird because I shouldn't be getting this error if it's already being linked.

Comment: I don't know. My Linux build seems to work OK. There are so many different Linux distros and configurations and such that I really have no way to diagnose a problem like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All right, I found the answer just in case anyone wants to know how to fix, all you have to do is open the file in framework/framework.lua and scroll down until you see

```
  configuration "linux"
        links {"GL", "GLU"}
```

and change that to

```
configuration "linux"
        links {"GL", "GLU", "X11"}
```

Which would allow you to compile all of the tutorials.